# is there a way to automate downloading of wikipedia articles using special:export?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I want to be able to download full histories of a few thousand articles from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export and I am looking for a programmatic approach to automate it
I started the following in python but that doesn't get any useful result

```
query = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.api?title=Special:Export&pages=%s&history=1&action=submit" % 'Page_title_here'
f = urllib.urlopen(query)
s = f.read()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can download the history of everything here: http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20100130/enwiki-20100130-pages-meta-history.xml.bz2 (or http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/6430796 for a torrent)

Comment: how large is that file going to be?

Comment: 280GB, extracts to 5TB. But posting a Python solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the list of pages you want to download in the `pages` array and this should work. Run the script and it will print the XML file. Note that Wikipedia seems to block the `urllib` user agent, but I don't see anything on the pages that suggests automatically downloading is disallowed. Use at your own risk.

You can also add `'curonly':1` to the dictionary to fetch only the current version.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib

class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = "WikiDownloader"
urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()

query = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit"
pages = ['Canada']
data = { 'catname':'', 'wpDownload':1, 'pages':"\n".join(pages)}
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
f = urllib.urlopen(query, data)
s = f.read()
print(s)
```

Comment: See [Meta-Wiki](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) for User-Agent policy.

Comment: Great! Thanks :) Obviously the User-Agent specified above should be updated according to this policy.